# Convert DOCX to XSL-FO

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, xsl-fo, docx4j

I have a DOCX document and need to convert this into an XSL-FO 1.0 file (which should be used with an XML document to generate a PDF file later on).
I've found a few solutions out of Word, but all links to them don't work anymore.
So I decided to give Docx4J a try. With that I can generate a quite good PDF file, but not a XSL-FO file which a FOP renderer would accept.
Does anyone have a hint how to get a valid XSL-FO?

My current solution gives me a convert.xls.fo which I can't work with:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactoryBuilder;
import org.docx4j.Docx4J;
import org.docx4j.convert.out.FOSettings;
import org.docx4j.convert.out.fo.renderers.FORendererApacheFOP;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileOutputStream os = null;
   try {
      InputStream templateInputStream = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\xx\\Documents\\test.docx");
      WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(templateInputStream);
      String outputfilepath = "C:\\Users\\xx\\Documents\\convert.pdf";
      os = new FileOutputStream(outputfilepath);
      FOSettings settings = new FOSettings(wordMLPackage);            
      settings.setFoDumpFile(new java.io.File(outputfilepath + ".fo"));
      FopFactoryBuilder fopFactoryBuilder = FORendererApacheFOP.getFopFactoryBuilder(settings);
      FORendererApacheFOP.getFOUserAgent(settings, fopFactoryBuilder.build());
              Docx4J.toFO(settings, os, Docx4J.FLAG_EXPORT_PREFER_XSL);
                  
      os.flush();
      os.close();
      System.out.println("Convert DONE!!!!");
   } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();   
   }finally{
         try {
           os.flush();
       } catch (IOException e1) {
           e1.printStackTrace();
       }
         try {
           os.close();
       } catch (IOException e1) {
           e1.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with the generated FO file?  Also, note you are writing FO to your outputfilepath but giving it a ".pdf" extension.

Comment: Maybe I mix up some wording/specs regarding FO and XSL. So please excuse me if I write something wrong.
The Apache FOP tells me that the source xsl is not a valid stylesheet.
And, if I switch the PDF extension to XSL I'll get a PDF as well, just with a XSL extension.
The only part which I could use is the FO dump file. But renamed to XSL the FOP gives me the above exception.

Comment: If you create XSL-FO output using Docx4J.toFO, then you should be able to process it using Apache FOP.  Alternatively, if you create PDF output using docx4j with docx4j-export-fo on your classpath, then that uses Apache FOP under the covers.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: With the code above and line String outputfilepath = "C:\\Users\\xx\\Documents\\convert.pdf"; changed to "...\convert.xsl";" I get the convert.xsl with content:
%PDF-1.4
%ª«¬­
1 0 obj
<<
/Creator (Apache FOP Version 2.7)
/Producer (Apache FOP Version 2.7)
/CreationDate (D:20230118094932+01'00')
>>
endobj
And so on...

Nevertheless, now I've got the convert.xsl.fo working:
I needed to include the <xsl:stylesheet> tag and add a <xsl:template match="/">.
Then I can process it via FOP.

I simply need a XSL-FO stylesheet/template which I can upload into a portal to create PDF files.

Comment: Maybe I don't really understand XSL-FO. So I thought I can get a working XSL-FO template via Docx4j without adding basic tags.

Comment: %PDF-1.4 %ª .. is a PDF!  See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

To get XSL FO output using Docx4J.toFO, you actually need:

```
        FOSettings settings = new FOSettings(wordMLPackage); 
        settings.setApacheFopMime(FOSettings.INTERNAL_FO_MIME);
```

Comment: Yes, so the output equals the dump output. Is there a way to have the stylesheet and template tags automatically in the XSL?